# How to detech FIN (Close) in TCP connection

Tags: android

I'm just now learning how to use the Android/Java Socket class and I need to respond in a particular way to a Close (FIN, really) sent by the remote computer.

The Socket class does not seem to be event-driven  (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) i.e., there don't seem to be any *onThis* or *onThat* handlers, so what's the best way to become aware of when the remote computer sends a FIN?

Currently the Android OS responds to the FIN with an ACK, but I need to do things in my application as well so I need a way for my app to be alerted to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, as an application programmer, rarely if ever need to even *care* about FINs and ACKs.  They're built into the TCP/IP stack, and the OS will take care of all that for you.  You're going too low-level for your own good; if you really want to mess with that stuff, then you won't be able to use `Socket` -- you'd need to get into raw sockets and such, which is way more work than you're ready for.  (I'm not sure if Java or Android would even *let* you do it.)

As for detecting the other end closing its side of the connection (which is basically what a FIN is), just read from the socket.  If the other end has shut down its sending side, a read will read 0 bytes (or return `-1`, depending on whether you're trying to read a bunch of bytes or just one).